# how to save image in the activity from galley?

Tags: android

I am recently trying to save image and text with sharedpreferences, but saving image does not go well.

this is the main activity code :

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    Button uploading = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload_upload);
    uploading.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // UPLOAD BUTTON

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            float scale = (float) (1024/(float)bitmap.getWidth());
            int image_w = (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * scale);
            int image_h = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * scale);
            Bitmap resize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, image_w, image_h, true);
            resize.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


            Intent intent = new Intent(upload.this,MainActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
            intent.putExtra("integer", 300);
            intent.putExtra("double", 3.141592);
            intent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
```

and this is the subactivity which sets image.

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_image);

        byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: There are no shared preferences in your code. Moreover: storing images in shared preferences looks a bad idea to me. Why do you want it?

Comment: `how to save image in the activity ...` Do you want to tranfer the bitmap to another activity instead? Pretty unsure what you want.

Comment: Actually I  am able to transfer image to another activity.  What I want is using activity life-cycle for the image.

Comment: ????? Can you edit your post to make better clear what you want. You also got an answer where you did not react on... You caused the confusion yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert image into Base64 string representation by using below code:

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);


SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit=shre.edit();
edit.putString("image_data",encodedImage);
edit.commit();
```

and then, when retrieving, convert it back into bitmap:

```
SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String previouslyEncodedImage = shre.getString("image_data", "");

if( !previouslyEncodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase("") ){
    byte[] b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    imageConvertResult.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```